# SAPUI5 Tile Container only shows 2 tiles

Tags: sapui5

I have copied the same example from [OpenUI5 Tile Container Sample](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview)

but I can't make it working I only see 2 tiles

I have seen in different similar posts that recommends to add `enableScrolling="false"` to page tag but is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is intermittent and relevant to Google Chrome. It's related on how the browser handles the asynchronous request made by `jQuery.sap.getModulePath()`. 
I have tested in Firefox Developer Edition and it's working properly. Anyway, here's how to fix it:

If you comment out that line in your controller and define the JSON data to the variable sPath it works (I have made the JSON data shorter to keep the answer clean but the live demo is full, see link below).

*Page.controller.js, line 12.*

```
//var sPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.m.sample.TileContainer", "/data.json");
var sPath = {"TileCollection":[{"icon":"sap-icon://hint","type":"Monitor","title":"Tiles: a modern UI design pattern for overview & navigation."},{"icon":"sap-icon://inbox","number":"89","title":"Approve Leave Requests","info":"Overdue","infoState":"Error"},{"type":"Create","title":"Create Leave Requests","info":"28 Days Left","infoState":"Success"},{"icon":"sap-icon://travel-expense-report","number":"281","numberUnit":"euro","title":"Travel Reimbursement","info":"1 day ago"},{"icon":"sap-icon://loan","number":"2380","numberUnit":"euro","title":"My Salary","info":"8 days ago"}]};
```

Working example:
[Tile Container](https://simpletilecontainer-i838198trial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/)